# adding values from DOM to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, dom

I am stuck at this, and all help would be appreciated it. I am trying to add the values to an array. right now I am trying to identify if there is a quantity on my input, if there isn't then I am to add item price times quantity. but is adding all the prices, including the ones that have no quantity on the input.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var cartArray = [];
var ItemNode, quantityNode, costNode, submitButton, subtotalNode, totalNode, output;

function init(){
 itemNode = document.querySelector('.input-item');
 costNode = document.querySelectorAll('.posterPrice');
 quantityNode = document.querySelectorAll('.qtyValue');
 submitButton = document.querySelectorAll("button");
 subtotalNode = document.getElementById('subtotal');
 totalNode = document.querySelector('#total');
 output = document.querySelector('.output');
  
 for (var i = 0; i < submitButton.length; i++){
  submitButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
  addPrice();
 });
 }
}



function addPrice(){
 addToCart();
}

function addToCart(){
 for (var k = 0; k < quantityNode.length; k++){
  for (var j = 0; j < costNode.length; j++){
  if(quantityNode[k].value !== false){
   cartArray.push(costNode[j].innerText * quantityNode[k].value);
  }
 } 
 console.log(cartArray);  
}

}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 2px solid red;
}
*/
#poster1 {
 background-image: url(img/poster7.png);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
}

#poster2 {
 background-image: url(img/poster2.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
}

.posterInfo {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 300px;
}

.posterInfo input {
 width: 45px;
}
/*.wrapper input {
 width: 45px;
 display: block;
}*/

.total {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Gallery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id='test'>Posters</h1>
 <div class="posters">
  <div id="poster1">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">2.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="poster2">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">3.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="poster3"></div>
  <div id="poster4"></div>
  <div id="poster5"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="total output">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span id="subtotal"></span></p>
  <p>Taxes: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Shipping: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p> 
 </div>
 <!--<script src="main.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to calculate each price of items. problem of your code is `for-loop`.

To calculate each price, it has to calculate each same index between `quantityNode` and `costNode`. that is, First item of `cartArray` is `quantityNode[0]` * `costNode[0]` and second item of `cartArray` is `quantityNode[1]` * `costNode[1]`.

I suggest that you finds a value using `find`. If you want to update the price when press the button `Add to Cart`, you should be empty `cartArray` by re-initializing to `[]`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var cartArray = [];
var ItemNode, quantityNode, costNode, submitButton, subtotalNode, totalNode, output;

function init(){
 itemNode = document.querySelector('.input-item');
 costNode = document.querySelectorAll('.posterPrice');
 quantityNode = document.querySelectorAll('.qtyValue');
 submitButton = document.querySelectorAll("button");
 subtotalNode = document.getElementById('subtotal');
 totalNode = document.querySelector('#total');
 output = document.querySelector('.output');
  
 for (var i = 0; i < submitButton.length; i++){
  submitButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
  addPrice();
 });
 }
}



function addPrice(){
 addToCart();
}

function addToCart(){
    $('.posterInfo').each(function(idx, elem) {
        cartArray.push(
            $(elem).find('.posterPrice').text() * $(elem).find('.qtyValue').val()
            );
    });
 console.log(cartArray);  
}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 2px solid red;
}
*/
#poster1 {
 background-image: url(img/poster7.png);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
}

#poster2 {
 background-image: url(img/poster2.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
}

.posterInfo {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 300px;
}

.posterInfo input {
 width: 45px;
}
/*.wrapper input {
 width: 45px;
 display: block;
}*/

.total {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Gallery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id='test'>Posters</h1>
 <div class="posters">
  <div id="poster1">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">2.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="poster2">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">3.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="poster3"></div>
  <div id="poster4"></div>
  <div id="poster5"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="total output">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span id="subtotal"></span></p>
  <p>Taxes: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Shipping: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p> 
 </div>
 <!--<script src="main.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```